# How to correlate instrumentation from Azure function app to Azure logic app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

We are going to implement a middleware project using Azure integration services like service bus, event grid, function app, logic app etc. The flow of data will be from an application in Salesforce cloud to an Azure App service, but there will be some data processing and transformation in the integration layer which will be implemented using Azure function apps and Azure logic apps.
For an integration trail like below to trace the flow of data we have used the same Application Insights across components and we have used correlation ID:
SF Application -> Service Bus -> Function App -> Table Storage -> Logic App -> SQL Server Database

The problem is Logic App logs are going to Azure Monitor and we could not use the same correlation ID in the Logic App. So in Azure Application Insight we are not getting the continuous trace of data through all these components. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, azure logic app can not be logged by application insights. It can just be logged by azure monitor with log analytics workspace. If you still want this feature, you can vote up for this feature on azure [feedback page](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/19493713-integration-with-application-insights).

Here provide an idea which may help you to implement the requirement(I'm not sure). You can create an azure function to log events and add the function to your logic app. And another way is use custom connector, provide a [custom connector](https://github.com/CoditEU/application-insights-connector) for application insight in logic app which may help you.